# Iterm2 terminal for mac

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan, iterm2, iterm

Is it possible to show iterm2 always in the top of the screen, even if my currenct app in running in the fullscreen mode? For example, I want to able run chrome and iterm2 in the same time when browser is in the fullscreen. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Though the setting isn't clearly named for this.

1. Open iTerm
2. Go to Preferences (cmd-,)
3. Go to Advanced Tab
4. Search for "dock"
5. Change the "Hide iTerm2 from the dock and from the cmd-Tab app switcher" to Yes
6. Restart iTerm2